# scroll to and change active state

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I know this problem has been asked before, but sorry.. i can't get it working!
i've made a onepager.. and it needs to scroll to a specific section and than change the active state(navbar)...

This is what i have so far.. it's not ideal but yeah..

https://jsfiddle.net/70jzb4s0/

```
<!--Navbar -->
<header class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-wrap">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#start"> <span class="brand-green"><img src="img/logo.png"/></a>
    </div>
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" role="navigation">
      <ul id="menu-hoofdmenu" class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#start" class="active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#over">Over</a></li>
        <li><a href="#diensten">Diensten</a></li>
        <li><a href="#referenties">Referenties</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>    
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<!-- End navbar -->


<section id="#start"></section>
<section id="over"></section
```

*edit*
Yes this is what i use

```
 var sections = $('section')
    , nav = $('nav')
    , nav_height = nav.outerHeight();

  $(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var cur_pos = $(this).scrollTop();

    sections.each(function() {
      var top = $(this).offset().top - nav_height,
          bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();

      if (cur_pos >= top && cur_pos <= bottom) {
        nav.find('a').removeClass('active');
        sections.removeClass('active');

        $(this).addClass('active');
        nav.find('a[href="#'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').addClass('active');
      }
    });
  });

  nav.find('a').on('click', function () {
    var $el = $(this)
      , id = $el.attr('href');

    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(id).offset().top - nav_height
    }, 500);
```

Comment: Did you try to solve it with jQuery? Can we see it?

Comment: So, the scrolling works, right? Your only problem is changing the active state of your navbar?

Comment: Yep, my scrolling works.. can't get the active state right

Comment: You could just create an `.active` class and set it when clicked. `$el.addClass('active')`.

Comment: yes, but it needs te detect when you are at a specific section.. the active state must change also then

Comment: Ah okay, I now understood. I'll have a look.